# Mocking a method which takes String as a parameter Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a method which takes String as a parameter, Based on the string value i wanted to return different values, below is my Sample code

```
when(mockVariableResolver.resolveVariable(
    (FacesContext)anyObject(),      
     Mockito.eq(ProgramConstants.SRCH_PROC_DATA_BEAN))).
thenReturn(searchProcedureCodeDataBean);
```

The resolveVariable metjos takes an object and a string, Object might be anything but the second argument must match, The above one did not worked.

**EDIT:**

Signature for resolveVariable metod is

```
fc.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(fc,
                                        "#{" + ProgramConstants.SRCH_PROC_DATA_BEAN + "}")
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: What exactly happens? Nothing? Exception?

Comment: It is not maching to the provided method..

Comment: It doesn't sound like there's enough information to diagnose the problem. So here are my default questions: If the resolveVariable method final? Is the resolveVariable overloaded, thus ambiguous? Does it work if you provide null and null?

Comment: Please show us the signature of your `resolveVariable` method. If you can create a self-contained example that demonstrates your problem, that would be helpful (for us and you).

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least for me). Please provide prototype of `resolveVariable()` and try to explain clearly what do you want to achieve. What must match?

Comment: And have you used `@Mock` or `initMocks()` correctly...

Comment: Does the `resolveVariable()` method return a `Mock`?

Comment: Basically it is JSF application resolveVariable method is used to get the managed bean value based on mapping string

Comment: Pleas show how your mock object `mockVariableResolver` is created. And as others pointed out provide the signature of `resolveVariable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, I would implement it as [Mockito.Answer](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html):

```
when(mock.resolveVariable(anyObject(), anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        String secondArgument = (String) args[1];
        //
        // TODO: make return value depend from secondArgument
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: How can i create this as saparate method and call every time, Since i have to call this when in multiple places.

Comment: convert the anonymous class to a local class

Comment: Sina72 Thanks for the reply, if so how can i pass Invocation to the answer method??

Comment: Invocation is filled by the mock object. Just add it to the when().thenAnswer().

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but perhaps

```
when( mockVariableResolver )
    .resolveVariable( (FacesContext)anyObject(),      
                      Mockito.eq( ProgramConstants.SRCH_PROC_DATA_BEAN ) ) )
    .thenReturn( searchProcedureCodeDataBean );
```

will do the trick.

Note that the `resolveVariable()` method is moved outside the `when()` argument list, which should always [be just a `@Mock`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2).

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but the resolveVariable is method in mockVariableResolver class. Getting Compilation error on resolveVariable method